# SSRS2008: Show Row Count of SubReport in Main Report

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, subreport

Using SSRS 2008
Have Main Report with text and 3 hidden subreports embedded in the main report.  There are three SubReports (Current, Expired and Missing) which provide detail information for the report (Parameter) you select in the main report. These work properly.

What I want to do is add a table to the Main report that displays a row count of the products displayed in the subreport.
For Instance:
Current
Product#1 Location CountofCurrent#1
Product#2 Location CountofCurrent#2
Expired
Product#1 Location CountofExpired#1
Product#2 Location CountofExpired#2
etc

I have been trying:

```
[Reports]![YourReportName]![YourSubReportName]!CountRows([TheValueFromTheSubReportYouWantToReference])
```

in different variations without success.

How do you reach from the main report and count the rows in the subreport?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just have 3 datasets in the main report that have the queries from the subreports to produce the row count based on the parameter?

Comment: 1) if kept detail report then queries run twice (once in Main, once in subreport)  2) Fair amount of rework

Comment: @WEI_DBA is correct. If you pare down the query to the absolute minimum and only return the row count it shouldn't be to bad.